Estimating conditional mutual information of discrete random variables with large domains
Given a dataset I want to estimate the conditional mutual information $I(X;Y|Z,W)$ for random variables $X, Y, Z, W$. The issue I'm facing is that the domains are rather large (say $\{0, \dots, 2^{12}\}$), hence computing joint probablities is intractable. Is there a way to get an approximation of this nevertheless?

are the $2^12$ some kind of histogram of some joint continuous RV?
